# Updating Control From Different Form

Tags: c#, user-interface, controls, updates

I've got a Main Form (frm_Main) and Settings Form (frm_Settings) and I would like to update a control, which is in frm_Main, from frm_Settings. So far I've tried adding a method in frm_Main and then accessing that from frm_Settings in hopes for it to work but it did't. Here is the code for my current method:

**Main Form**

```
public partial class frm_Main : Form
{
    public frm_Main()
    {

    }

    public void ChangeBackColor(Color color)
    {
        richTextBox.BackColor = color;
    }
}
```

**Settings Form**

```
public partial class frm_Settings : Form
{
    public frm_Settings()
    {

    }

    private void pbcl_editorBackColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog editorBackColor = new ColorDialog();
        if (editorBackColor.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Variables.Editor_BackColor = "#" + editorBackColor.Color.ToArgb().ToString("X");
            Color colour = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Variables.Editor_ForeColor);
            var Main = new frm_Main();
            Main.ChangeBackColor(colour);
        }
    }
}
```

Upon click the 'OK' button on the ColorSelectorDialog, nothing happens, there is no update whatsoever. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Settings.cs

```
public partial class frm_Settings : Form
{
    private frm_Main _main;
    public frm_Settings(frm_Main main)
    {
          _main = main;
    }

    private void pbcl_editorBackColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog editorBackColor = new ColorDialog();
        if (editorBackColor.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Variables.Editor_BackColor = "#" + editorBackColor.Color.ToArgb().ToString("X");
            Color colour = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Variables.Editor_ForeColor);                
            _main.ChangeBackColor(colour);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.cs

```
public partial class frm_Main : Form
{
    public frm_Main()
    {

    }
    private void LaunchSetting()
    {
       var settings = new frm_Settings(this);
       settings.ShowDialog();
    }
    public void ChangeBackColor(Color color)
    {
        richTextBox.BackColor = color;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

We can also handle it to create an event

Settings.cs

```
public partial class frm_Settings : Form
{
    public delegate void ColorChangedHandler(Color color);
    public event ColorChangedHandler OnColorChangedHandler;
    public frm_Settings()
    {

    }

    private void pbcl_editorBackColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog editorBackColor = new ColorDialog();
        if (editorBackColor.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Variables.Editor_BackColor = "#" + editorBackColor.Color.ToArgb().ToString("X");
            Color colour = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Variables.Editor_ForeColor);
            if (OnColorChangedHandler != null)
            {
               OnColorChangedHandler(colour);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Main.cs

```
public partial class frm_Main : Form
{
    public frm_Main()
    {

    }
    private void LaunchSetting()
    {
       var settings = new frm_Settings(this);
       settings.OnColorChangedHandler += OnColorChanged;
       settings.ShowDialog();
    }
    private void OnColorChanged(Color color)
    {
       ChangeBackColor(color);
    }
    public void ChangeBackColor(Color color)
    {
        richTextBox.BackColor = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide an explantation of why it worked. It is rather simple and should be easy to explain.

Comment: @deathismyfriend This is common mistake of every initial stage developer that they create new instance to use something rather than use existing. In this issue before settings color he was creating new object on the main form which is never shown

Comment: I know this is common as I once had this problem. But showing someone the solution rather than explaining the solution and then showing them is different. One being some only learn when things are explained. It is better for a short explanation so that future viewers get a better grasp on the solution and the error they have made.